# Future continuous "going to"

Tags: verbs, tenses

The future continuous tense is made by combining "will" with "be" + present participle, e.g. *He will be speaking*.

The future simple can use "will" or "going to", i.e. *He will speak* and *He is going to speak*.

Using this logic, is a sentence such as *He is going to be speaking* future continuous (going to), or is it present continuous + "be" + present participle?

Comment: Isn't that the same tense  as *He is about to speak*? How is that any different from the *Is going to* case? I'm pretty sure those are the same tense.

Comment: To me it looks like future continuous.